# Is this code nonportable or unsafe

Tags: c, malloc

I'm writing some code that depends on calloc and was wondering it would be safe to repoint the pointer to stack space if calloc failed, then set the pointer to NULL before the call to free() or skip it altogether.
    Works great of my 386 linux box.

```
char *str = NULL;
int usestackspace = 0;
char str1[16] = {0};

str = (char *)calloc(1, sizeof(pid_t));

if (str == NULL) {
    sleep(1);
    str = (char *)calloc(1, sizeof(pid_t));
}

if (str == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "watchdog: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    usestackspace = 1;
    str = str1;
}

if (str == NULL) {
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: The `free` and the `str = NULL;` are pointless, but otherwise it looks OK.

Comment: You shouldn't edit the code in the question without any indication of it. I spent a few minutes looking for a free before realizing you took it out of the question.

Comment: The `return -1;` in revision 4 of the question is dead code. An optimizing compiler may omit the third `if` altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `str1` doesn't go out of scope your code is pretty much fine.  You do have one real error (that should be generating a warning, though it probably doesn't matter at runtime):

- `str = &str1` isn't a valid assignment without an explicit cast.  You probably want `str = str1`.

One potential problem:

- If you were depending on the implicit setting-to-zero of memory by `calloc`, you need to initialize `str1`.  Use `char str1[16] = { 0 }` or call `memset`, for example.

And a couple of minor notes:

1. You don't have to cast the return value of `calloc` in a C program.
2. You have `free(str)` and `str = NULL` in the `if` statement, but both are no-ops - the `if` statement condition ensures that `str` already *is* `NULL`.